# How can I find out if the USB-C port on my laptop has video output (for adapter USB-C - HDMI)?

Tags: hardware, xrandr, usb-device, hdmi, lsusb

I have tried to use a hub with hdmi port that connects to the USB-C port of my computer but this one doesn't work.

Checking other similar threads on Internet (and here), I see that the problem is probably that the USB-C port in question does not support video output (the hub itself has USB ports and they work properly).

So is there a way to demonstrate it from my PC to stay calm? Ar can I only check it using the manufacturer's documentation?

For more info:

`lsusb -t` before hub attachment:

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 10000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 2, If 3, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

`lsusb -t` after hub attachment:

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 10000M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 2, If 3, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 41, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/5p, 480M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

`xrander` output before and after hub attachment:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170m
   1920x1080     60.01*+  59.93
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88
   1400x1050     59.98
   1600x900      60.00    59.95    59.82
   1280x1024     60.02
   1400x900      59.96    59.88
   1280x960      60.00
   1368x768      60.00    59.88    59.85
   1280x800      59.81    59.91
   1280x720      59.86    60.00    59.74
   1024x768      60.00
   1024x576      60.00    59.90    59.82
   960x540       60.00    59.63    59.82
   800x600       60.32    56.25
   864x486       60.00    59.92    59.57
   640x480       59.94
   720x405       59.51    60.00    58.99
   640x360       59.84    59.32    60.00
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

And `xrandr` after HDMI port monitor attachment:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
   1920x1080     60.01*+  59.93
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88
   1400x1050     59.98
   1600x900      60.00    59.95    59.82
   1280x1024     60.02
   1400x900      59.96    59.88
   1280x960      60.00
   1368x768      60.00    59.88    59.85
   1280x800      59.81    59.91
   1280x720      59.86    60.00    59.74
   1024x768      60.00
   1024x576      60.00    59.90    59.82
   960x540       60.00    59.63    59.82
   800x600       60.32    56.25
   864x486       60.00    59.92    59.57
   640x480       59.94
   720x405       59.51    60.00    58.99
   640x360       59.84    59.32    60.00
HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm x 270mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94
   1680x1050     59.88
   1600x900      60.00
   1280x1024     60.02
   1440x900      59.90
   1280x800      59.91
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94
   1024x768      60.00
   800x600       60.32
   720x576       50.00
   720x480       60.00    59.94
   640x480       60.00    59.94
   720x400       70.08
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, my laptop's USB-C doesnt support Video output, and it seems that it cannot be demonstrated by software, just going to the hardware manufacturer.

Therefore I had to install a USB 3.0 to HDMI adapter that supports `displaylink` drivers and install it to get a second external monitor.